# Git Detached at

Tags: git

I am new to git.

So I noticed Visual Studio said Detached at (and then a bunch of random letters and numbers).
I thought that looks odd and I clicked on it and saw that it said master so I switched to that and now two days of work seems to be gone.
Is there any way to restore it?

I looked at local but it seems to only have data from October 15.

Comment: You can try `git checkout BUNCHOFRANDOMLETTERSANDNUMBERS`. If you don't remember those letters and numbers, you can try `git reflog` and see if you recognize it, then try the previous command.

Comment: Also, you probably should set aside some time to follow a good tutorial or other resource that teaches git. Unfortunately there are plenty of commands that can make it appear that you've lost data and it's easy getting tripped up if you don't know what the tool is doing. Git is such an important tool, and it is here to stay, so it should be time well spent.

Comment: Git is basically a version manager. If you were able to easily switch to a branch without any prompt asking you to `please clean repository working tree before checkout`, your code is safe. I recommend a graph like view - to help you visualize the code. Try [git kraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). BTW you can also try using the `git cli` which can be run from your terminal / powershell.

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend. If you committed, you won't lose it, even if you moved away and lost the ID of the revisions you committed.

Comment: Thank you @LasseV.Karlsen. That did the trick. I have started learning Git but I wasn't comfortable enough to take a chance with what I know to get the work back. RefLog I haven't seen so far though. Like I mentioned I am new to git. :)

Comment: @eftshift0 Thank you I needed that info. This makes me more calm working with git.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen do you perhaps have any tutorial to recommend?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 0):

Check in visual studio that you see any other branch than master. If yes - and it's branch when you working before, you can merge it.

In other way, you can move your commits by command cherry-pick, but it's not good practise